# C++11: conditional compilation: members

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to make a struct with conditional members, that means, different members exists only with specific specializations. But, I want that this classes are fastest as possible. I've tried it in three differents ways:

**Way 1:**

```
 template<typename T, bool with_int = false>
 struct foo
 {
     template<typename... Args>
     foo(Args&&... args) : m_t(forward<Args>(args)...)
     {}

     T m_t;
 }

 template<typename T>
 struct foo<T, true>
 {
     template<typename... Args>
     foo(Args&&... args) : m_t(forward<Args>(args)...), m_id(0)
     {}

      T m_t;
      int m_id;
 };
```

- Disadventage: repeated code for each specialization.

**Way 2:**

```
 template<typename T, bool with_int = false>
 struct foo
 {
     template<typename... Args>
     foo(Args&&... args) : m_t(forward<Args>(args)...)
     {}

     virtual ~foo() {}

     T m_t;
 }

 template<typename T>
 struct foo<T, false> : public foo<T>
 {
      using foo<T>::foo;

      int m_id = 0;
 };
```

- Adventage: few code.
- Disadventage: Use of vtables/inheritance/etc: more time in construction or access to members? But, in other way, I don't pretend to to use "references" to base class. What is it the real adventages or disadventages of this aproach?

**Way 3**

```
 using nil_type = void*;
 using zero_type = nil_type[0];

 template<typename T, bool with_int = false>
 struct foo
 {
    template<typename... Args, typename = typename enable_if<with_int>::type>
    foo(Args&&... args) : m_t(forward<Args>(args)...), m_int(0)
    {}

    template<typename... Args, typename = typename enable_if<!with_int>::type>
    foo(Args&&... args) : m_t(forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}        

    T m__t;
    typename conditional<with_int, int, zero_type>::type m_int;
 };
```

- Ventages: Write code once; when `with_int` is `false`, field `m_int` has size 0 (almost with gcc 4.7.2).
- Adventages: More use of templates (reduce readability) and I'm not sure about how compilers deal with member of size 0. I don't know indeed to what extent a size-0-field is dangerous or has sense. Repeated constructors, but perhaps this is avoidable.

What is the best approach or method?

Comment: OT, but I'm pretty sure names containing a double underscore are reserved for the compiler so you should go with `m_int` and `m_t`.

Comment: I think only members **beginning** with double underscore, but not containing it.

Comment: Nope, see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier): `Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use.`

Comment: Note that you can't have a member of size 0, the compiler will still allocate a non-zero size for it. &Var1 == &Var2 if and only if Var1 and Var2 are the same variable. Any variable that has size 0 would violate that.

Comment: Then, `sizeof` lies? `sizeof` said me `zero_type` has a size 0, `foo<int, false>` size 4, and `foo<int, true>` size 8. It is the same with `struct { char m[0] };`: `sizeof` returns 0 with it.

Comment: Still, the given equivalence has to hold. The compiler will just insert padding bytes in your struct to accomplish that.

Comment: You could use a tuple for a data member. `tuple<T,int>` or `tuple<T>` depending on that template parameter.

Comment: Arrays with size 0 are illegal. What you could use in 3rd approach is [Boost Compressed Pair](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/compressed_pair.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered inheritance?

```
template< bool >
struct foo_int_base
{
  // stuff without the int
  void f(); // does not use m_id
};

template<>
struct foo_int_base< true >
{
  // stuff with the int
  int m_id = 0;
  void f(); // uses m_id
};

template< typename T, bool with_int = false >
struct foo : foo_int_base< with_int >
{
  // common stuff here
};
```

Comment: Use of inheritance is contempled in my second aproach. Read it please and my questions just below.

Comment: Your approach is different, is uses `virtual` (which has a cost) and it tries to derive the int-case from the non-int-case which will IMHO make things more complicated and provide no clear separation. But it's just my suggestion, I can't know if this could work for you.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Note that the _additional_ size of `foo_int_base<false>` is 0 (certainly in optimized builds). Unlike members, base class subobjects can have zero size.