# Conditionally defined variable (static if)

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, constexpr, template-meta-programming

In multiple cases I would want to use something like

```cpp
template<bool condition>
struct S
{
  int value;
  if constexpr(condition) /*#if condition*/
    double my_extra_member_variable;
  /*#endif*/
}
```

or

```cpp
if constexpr(sizeof...(Ts) != 0)
  // define something extra ( a tuple or so )
```

This is possible with preprocessor flags, but we want to be the "cool kids" that don't use preprocessor flags, but rather metaprogramming

It could also work with specilizations in some cases, but assume you have multiple conditions, and multiple member variables that need to be conditionally activated, it could get nasty quite fast.

I tried

```
constexpr in_series_production_mode = false;
struct dummy{ dummy(auto& x){}; operator=(auto& x){return *this;} }; /*1 byte*/
struct debug_data_t { /* lots of parameters with big size*/};

template <typename T>
using maybe_empty = typename std::conditional<in_series_production_mode ,T,dummy>::type; 

maybe_empty<debug_data_t> my_debugging_variable;
```

But with that you still get 1 byte for the unused `dummy` variable. While if you used `#if` of something similar you would have needed 0 bytes.

Does anybody know a better practice for that?

Comment: i dont understand the question. `if constexpr (...) T t;` is discarded when the condition is false. You dont have to be a "cool kid" to use it

Comment: If you try to compile that 
```template<int x> struct S { int a; if contstexpr(x>0) double b;};```
probably won't compile .. or ?

Comment: no. You didnt mention that it is for a member. You can specialize `S` such that `S<false>`  does not have certain members while `S<true>` does have them

Comment: yup, it would work fine for one specilization

but if you have multiple conditions like ```if(x>2) && (x<4) ...``` and so on 
or you have  multiple member variables/fcns  ```if(x>3) double c;``` as well, 
it could messy quite fast

Comment: why would it be messy? `S<true,false,true>` has the first member not the second but the third. Can you show how you would use the struct and its member?

Comment: related / dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15473643/4117728

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++20, the "good enough" solution is with the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute

```
struct empty_t {};

template<bool condition>
struct S {
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<condition, double, empty_t> var;
};
```

It's not perfect because `var` is always defined, but it will not take any space. Note that if there are multiple variables, you will need them to be different types, e.g.

```
template<int>
struct empty_t {};

template<bool condition>
struct S {
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<condition, double, empty_t<0>> var; 
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<condition, double, empty_t<1>> rav;
};
```

Comment: Great idea, thanks ...^^ ..

Does it have to be `empty_t<int>` ?
Would it work with `empty` with no templates as well?

Comment: "*if there are multiple variables, you will need them to be different types*" - why?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's a simplification. `no_unique_address` actually means "maybe no unique address if the types involved are different". Two objects of the same type having the same address is the same object. That can't happen, so they have different addresses.

Comment: @PasserBy [according to this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address), the types don't matter at all, only the names.

Comment: @RemyLebeau See the comments in the example. Also notice how it's worded "need not", as in the attribute isn't a strict requirement. The compiler can in fact ignore the attribute completely.